# How to sort a 'query_posts' function by custom field, while limiting posts by another custom field

Tags: php, wordpress, loops, posts

I'm querying a series of posts in WP with the following function:

```
<?php 
$thirtydays = date('Y/m/d', strtotime('+30 days'));
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
query_posts( array( 
    'post_type' => array('post', 'real-estate'), 
    'meta_key' => 'Time          Available', 
    'meta_compare' => '<=', 
    'meta_value' => $thirtydays, 
    'paged' => $paged )); 
?>
```

This part is working fine. It's basically pulling all my Real Estate posts, but only returning results that have a 'Time Available' of 30 days or less.

I need this to also order the posts in ascending order from low to high using the data from another custom field, 'Price.'

Whenever I add the standard `'orderby' => 'meta_value', 'meta_key' => 'Price'` it no longer shows results within 30 days.

Is there any way I can combine these two? And is it possible to add a button which re-runs the query and sorts by Price, Bedrooms,  etc? Or is this too specific for WP?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe this will provide you want you need. It's a class called `PostsOrderedByMetaQuery` that extends `WP_Query` and accepts new arguments `'orderby_meta_key'` and '`orderby_order'`:

```
class PostsOrderedByMetaQuery extends WP_Query {
  var $posts_ordered_by_meta = true;
  var $orderby_order = 'ASC';
  var $orderby_meta_key;
  function __construct($args=array()) {
    add_filter('posts_join',array(&$this,'posts_join'),10,2);
    add_filter('posts_orderby',array(&$this,'posts_orderby'),10,2);
    $this->posts_ordered_by_meta = true;
    $this->orderby_meta_key = $args['orderby_meta_key'];
    unset($args['orderby_meta_key']);
    if (!empty($args['orderby_order'])) {
      $this->orderby_order = $args['orderby_order'];
      unset($args['orderby_order']);
    }
    parent::query($args);
  }
  function posts_join($join,$query) {
    if (isset($query->posts_ordered_by_meta)) {
      global $wpdb;
      $join .=<<<SQL
INNER JOIN {$wpdb->postmeta} postmeta_price ON postmeta_price.post_id={$wpdb->posts}.ID
       AND postmeta_price.meta_key='{$this->orderby_meta_key}'
SQL;
    }
    return $join;
  }
  function posts_orderby($orderby,$query) {
    if (isset($query->posts_ordered_by_meta)) {
      global $wpdb;
      $orderby = "postmeta_price.meta_value {$this->orderby_order}";
    }
    return $orderby;
  }
}
```

You would call it like this:

```
$thirtydays = date('Y/m/d', strtotime('+30 days'));
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
$query = new PostsOrderedByMetaQuery(array(
  'post_type' => array('post', 'real-estate'),
  'meta_key' => 'Time Available',
  'meta_compare' => '<=',
  'meta_value' => $thirtydays,
  'paged' => $paged,
  'orderby_meta_key' => 'Price',
  'orderby_order'    => 'DESC',
));
foreach($query->posts as $post) {
  echo " {$post->post_title}\n";
}
```

You can copy the `PostsOrderedByMetaQuery` class to your theme's `functions.php` file, or you can use it within a `.php` file of a plugin you may be writing.

If you want to test it quickly I've posted [**a self-contained version of the code**](https://gist.github.com/665303) to Gist which you can download and copy to your web server's root as `test.php`, modify for your use case, and then request from your browser using a URL like `http://example.com/test.php`.

Hope this helps.

-Mike

P.S. This answer is [**very similar to an answer I just gave over at WordPress Answers**](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/3708/custom-taxonomy-wp-query-for-all-terms-in-a-taxonomy/3715#3715), which is the sister site of StackOverflow where lots of WordPress enthusiasts like me answer questions daily. You might want to [see that answer too](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/3708/custom-taxonomy-wp-query-for-all-terms-in-a-taxonomy/3715#3715) because it has a tad more explanation and because you might want to see [WordPress Answers](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/). Hope you'll consider posting your WordPress questions over [there](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/) too in the future?

Comment: I'm confused as to how to implement this. When I paste in the code, it just shows a block of text with post names. I've been using query_posts and pulling in fields dynamically for each post (ie. Featured Image, Title, Description, other custom fields, etc). How can I do that here? I tried replacing the "echo " {$post->post_title}\n";" part but it's not quite working.

Comment: Nevermind. I got it working! Only problem is, I can't figure out why the pagination won't show up.

Comment: @nurain - Maybe ask another question about pagination over at http://wordpress.stackexchange.com?  Be sure to include the theme code you are using because your question here doesn't include enough information to understand your issues with pagination.

Answer (score 0):

Because `'orderby' => 'meta_value'` requires `meta_key`, and your `meta_key` is already in use for a comparison, I don't think you can do this. `meta_key` only accepts a single value and not an array of options. This is definitely a limitation and I encourage you to open a request if you don't find a solution.

As far as the button to re-run the query, you could simply reload the page and pass a query variable to change the sort. Unfortunately you still have to solve the first part of your question.

#### UPDATE

You could always sort the returned array yourself using PHP.

Also, not sure what you are checking with time available but you could register a filter that may help you customize the query a bit further `add_filter('posts_where', ...);`  http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts