# Custom query for Wordpress Custom Post Type

Tags: php, wordpress

I have created a custom post type using "Types" plugin. The post type has some custom taxonomy and fields.

I want to query this post type using raw sql because I have to do some sorting and filtering based upon user request.

How can I do it using raw sql query?

A sample query would be extremely helpful. Thanks!

Comment: Do you have more information to provide?

Answer (score 1):

Please defer to http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Types

Specifically,

**Querying by post type**

You can also create new queries to display posts from a specific post type. This is done via the "post_type" parameter to a WP_Query.

Example:

```
$args = array( 'post_type' => 'product', 'posts_per_page' => 10 );
$loop = new WP_Query( $args );
while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
    the_title();
    echo '<div class="entry-content">';
    the_content();
    echo '</div>';
endwhile;
```

This simply loops through the latest 10 'product' custom-post types and displays the title and content of them.

---

As you can see form the above, your custom post types are stored in the same table as regular posts (and pages) they just have their post_type column set to your post type.

Comment: I have some fields like price, and I want to sort in ascending or descending order. How can I do it with WP_Query? Thanks!

Comment: Hi aryan -- are your fields (price, etc) stored as meta values?

Comment: Actually, they must be. There really isn't any other way to do it with WP. Please take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4111255/how-to-sort-a-query-posts-function-by-custom-field-while-limiting-posts-by-an to see if it answers -- if not, more inspection of the 'Types' plugin you are using will have to be done

Comment: I have created a couple of meta boxes using "Types" plugin. It seems that query_post can do the job. What do you think?

Comment: `query_posts` by itself will be good to pull your custom post types, but if you want to add sorting by custom meta keys, I believe you will have to add some filters to hook into WP before it executes the query, per the previous link =X

Comment: Can you please give me any reference or code snippet? Thanks a lot!