# Wordpress query_posts Order By Custom Field

Tags: wordpress, sql-order-by

i'm trying to order my results with query_posts function by a custom field.

Here is my edited query_posts() function:

```
query_posts( "post_type=produkte&".$query_string."&orderby=Price&order=DESC" );
```

The Price looks like that {Euro}.{Cent} for example 1.49.

And the query_posts() function orders it not right. The result is ordered like that:

0.49, 1.99, 0.99

What is going wrong?

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: what sheikh said, questions like these are asked often.. here the docs: http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Order_.26_Orderby_Parameters

Comment: The ref moved nowadays to https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#order-orderby-parameters

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You may try this (hopefully it'll work/found online)

```
query_posts( "post_type=produkte&".$query_string."&meta_key=Price&orderby=meta_value_num&order=DESC" );
```

Another answer on [**SO**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4111255/how-to-sort-a-query-posts-function-by-custom-field-while-limiting-posts-by-an).